# Devise in Rails did not create a route for creating a profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, authentication

I just created a bunch of routes with Devise, but one notable route was not created: to make an account.

Here is what I have in my migration:

create_table(:users, :options => 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8') do |t|
  t.database_authenticatable :null => false
  t.recoverable
  t.rememberable
  t.trackable
  t.confirmable
  t.encryptable

And here are my relevant rake routes

```
     new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
         user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
 destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
        user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
    new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                      PUT    /users/password(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
    user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
                      GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
```

Any idea why the create-profile route was not made and how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the **Registerable**-module. You probably need to add it to your User-model.

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :confirmable
end
```

Comment: Good call on that. One problem though.  I added the registrable to the user model and the migration I had used before, and then ran rake db:migrate and after that one I run the rake routes, none of the user routes come up.  Do you know where I went wrong?

Comment: So now no routes at all show up for Devise? I'm not sure you have to add registerable (with an e!) to the migration, it does not affect the database.

Comment: Yes you are right - taking it out of the migration fixed things!